# VS2017 Preview on Win10 Failed to connect MacOS Sierra

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a mac with macOS Sierra ver 10.12.5  and Win10 PC

in WinPC, I installed VS2017 Preview and in mac I installed Visual Studio for Mac ( there is no version like 2017..)

I follow the instruction to connect mac:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/

Observation:
When they connected. There is no link-icon show up beside the _ssh, the Xamarin Agent dialog box will closed.

The Connection status show at the bottom.

on the VS2017: 
made selection on the dropdown boxes: 1)Debug 2) iphoneSimulator 3)ProjectName.ios  4)Simulator

Click Simulator:

**problem:**

The installed Xamarin.iOS (version 10.10) on the Mac is not compatible with the local Xamarin.iOS (version 10.11). Double click here to select a new server.

What I should do? please help.

Thanks

Comment: The message says it all; the versions of Xamarin.iOS on your Windows and Mac are different. Update your Xamarin.iOS on your Mac. Just open up Xamarin Studio or VS4Mac click the menu in the top left and choose 'Check for updates...' it should be there.

Comment: This is where I am having problem. When click the Menu. It show Update Channel : Stable  --- Up to date .  Select Alpha, there is no download button or link? Can you show me how to download it? or should I change the Xamarin.iOS on WinPC? How? If they r connected, do I have to launch the VS4Mac ? How Do I select the iphone type? in VS in Win or Mac?

Comment: You either need to downgrade your Windows Xamarin.iOS version or upgrade the one on the Mac. It seems on Windows you're on the Alpha channel. To install a version manually log into your account at Xamarin.com and download a specific version from there

Comment: Me too am facing this problem